Level tiles in shower
First time tiling a shower. My understanding is that you should measure up a tile from the top of the tub and place a ledger board as a starting point.
Since we have a window in the shower, is it best to use the bottom of the window as the starting point and tile down to the tub making any minor cuts to the bottom row to make align nicely to the top of the tub?
Here are the tiles we are using if that helps as well.



What you are referring to is used to make sure the tiles are level in a shower.
Since a shower floor is pitched the bottom of the tile needs to be cut to match the pitch.  This is easier if the second row of tile is started level with a ledger board.
For a tub you don't need this since the tub edge should be level already.
You can choose to do the math to see if it is beneficial to trim the first course of tile to give you a better fit at the window.

what you should look at first is the edge tiles. make sure they won't need to be cut to some stupid width like 1/4"
Then look at the tiles under the window sill, if they can be full size while still satisfying the first condition that will probably look best, so do that. install the ledger to support that row of tiles that go under the window and work from there.
